# How to display date picker for android with only month and year fields?

Tags: android, sdk, datepicker

i want to disable the day selection option on the android sdk date picker. any easy xml configuration would be the best

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you searched for a solution using a search engine?

Comment: i did in fact and found people saying its impossible, which is not true but i dont have a clear idea about how to go forward with this but its possible. thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just have released a new date picker framework which allows you to create custom date picker. I also provided some example date pickers like the one you are looking for. Hope, that it works for you.

the code can be found here: https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider

**UPDATE 06/2014:**
This library was developed 2010 and has been unmaintained since 2011. So it is most likely out of date by now.

Comment: The custom date picker is a-w-s-o-m-e

Comment: Oh the joys of maintaining a Wordpress page... I updated the link to the GitHub repository

Comment: is it still relevant? could you please update the project to support gradle and android studio?

Comment: It's probably not relevant anymore. The project was developed when Android 2.3 was new. And hasn't been updated since. So there hopefully are better solutions out there. I'm not developing android apps anymore, so I'm totally out of the loop regarding modern practices. =/

Answer (score 15):

It possible to hack the DatePicker instance using reflection. This way, you are able to access the NumberPicker instance which represent the day in the DatePicker:

```
datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.expiration_date);
try {
    Field f[] = datePicker.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : f) {
        if (field.getName().equals("mDayPicker")) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object dayPicker = new Object();
            dayPicker = field.get(datePicker);
            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
} 
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Note that I had to change mDayPicker to mDaySpinner. I'm not sure on which API level introduced this change but I'm building for android 4.0.3 right now.

Comment: This may be broke in Android 5.0 and higher because the DatePicker does not use those number pickers anymore!

Comment: On Android 6, fields are mDelegate, LOG_TAG, MODE_CALENDAR, MODE_SPINNER. The solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking of reflection this works in Android 4.4.2 SDK

```
"mDaySpinner"
```

instead

```
"mDayPicker"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think It's the best solution

```
  datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as per the comment below, I wouldn't follow this answer anymore.

I don't think you can do that with the default date picker.  You'll have to create it out of basic Android UI elements.   But instead of going to that trouble, why not use a better library element like this great-looking iPhone-esque wheel:  http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/   I haven't used it yet, but I plan to!

Comment: This wasn't bad advice in Jan 2011, but if you're reading this now, I'd recommend not using a library that mimics iOS. Google doesn't like that: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: Users also don't like that

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in 2.2 version. But title of the dialog is not changed.

```
for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {           

    if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
        datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(datePickerDialog);

        Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {

            if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                Object dayPicker = new Object();
                dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker widget for backported compatibility and make the day picker 'gone'

```
<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

For Hiding Day :

```
 datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

&

For hiding Month :

```
datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```