# How to create custom datepicker?

Tags: android

I want create custom datepicker dialog which displays only month and year. Can anyone pls guide me how to do this?

Regards
Monali

Comment: you can try this link
http://misha.beshkin.lv/custom-datepicker-for-android/

Comment: I tried this..is there any other solution?

Comment: you may get help from this http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display date picker for android with only month and year fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields)

Comment: Start from here http://viswanathl.blogspot.in/2014/02/custom-calendar-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create/use a custom view, my best guess would be to try and use reflection, as [suggested below this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields). Except you will want to change that example to apply to the year field in stead.