# Customize android DatePicker to contain only month & year selection fields

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-actionbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display date picker for android with only month and year fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields)

I face a problem to customize the Android `DatePicker` widget. That's if I defined an `DatePicker` in my Android app code:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(...);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

How can I make this `DatePicker` only show **Month** and **Year** selection fields without **day** selection field on device screen?