# Android: Date picker with only month and the year

Tags: android, datetime

I am new to Android so please excuse for such a simple question. How to set only month and the year in Android Date Picker?
I don't want the date in it. Please help with this.

Comment: Android [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) contains clear code with examples. Have you visited that link first?

Comment: It doesn't say anything about hiding the date.

Comment: Check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields/18167466#18167466

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you can't do it with default date-picker

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the custom DATE PICKER with Month and Year Only. Here I have opened the Date Picker on the click of the edit text box.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private int mYear = 2013;
    private int mMonth = 5;
    private int mDay = 30;
    private EditText etPickADate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        etPickADate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_datePicker);
        etPickADate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListner = new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDate();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            /*
             * return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListner, mYear, mMonth,
             * mDay);
             */
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = this.customDatePicker();
            return datePickerDialog;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void updateDate() {
        int localMonth = (mMonth + 1);
        String monthString = localMonth < 10 ? "0" + localMonth : Integer
                .toString(localMonth);
        String localYear = Integer.toString(mYear).substring(2);
        etPickADate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(monthString).append("/").append(localYear).append(" "));
        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog customDatePicker() {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListner,
                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        try {
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
                if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField
                            .get(dpd);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType()
                            .getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                        if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName())
                                || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField
                                        .getName())) {
                            datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                            Object dayPicker = new Object();
                            dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return dpd;
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone wonders, this method uses reflection to set the Visibility of the day picker to GONE.