# Android Date selector with only Day and Month

Tags: android, datepicker

I am looking for a way to customize the Date selector in Android to only show the day and month (i.e. no year).

I am creating a dialog based on [How to display date picker for android with only month and year fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122929/how-to-display-date-picker-for-android-with-only-month-and-year-fields):

```
    Dialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerListener, dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    try {
        Field f[] = dlg.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : f) {
            String name = field.getName();
            if (name.equals("YEAR")){
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object dayPicker = new Object();
                dayPicker = field.get(dlg);
                ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        // TODO: should not happen
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dlg;
```

But I keep getting a Cast exception on ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   android.view.View

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here give this a go. Its APIv11+ but there are other ways on lower API versions.

```
DatePickerDialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerListener, 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
int year = context.getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/year", null, null);
if(year != 0){
    View yearPicker = dlg.getDatePicker().findViewById(year);
    if(yearPicker != null){
        yearPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
return dlg;
```

Updated code: This should do the job.

```
DatePickerDialog dlg = new DatePickerDialog(context, datePickerListener, 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
    dueDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int year = getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/year", null, null);
        if(year != 0){
            View yearPicker = findViewById(year);
            if(yearPicker != null){
                yearPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
};
return dlg;
```

Comment: I changed the yearPicker to View yearPicker = dlg.findViewById(year); to avoid the API level issue but it complies but returns null. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't find the year for me in Android 5.1 :(

Comment: yearPicker is null on api level 23.

Comment: On newer API levels the id of the year TextView in the header is "android:id/date_picker_header_year".

Answer (score 1):

This is Works for me :

```
DatePickerDialog monthDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, 
AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        monthTextView.setText(dayOfMonth+ "/" + (month + 1));
    }
}, yearNow, monthNow, dayNow){
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("year","id","android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
monthDatePickerDialog.setTitle("select_month");
monthDatePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: This may not work on some device due to manufacturer's modification in the SDK which also happens to me when I used `getIdentifier()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42807096/android-findviewbyidresources-getsystem-getidentifierday-id-android