# Android - findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day","id","android") not working

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-7.0-nougat

I was trying to show a datepicker with only **month** and **year**.

Here's my code:

```
Calendar todayDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        android.app.DatePickerDialog pickerDialog = new android.app.DatePickerDialog(
                new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(),
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar),
                new android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        updateDobButtonWithValue(button, i, i1, i2, sdfdisplay, sdfvalue, valuechangecallback);
                    }
                },
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );

        pickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(todayDate.getTimeInMillis());
        pickerDialog.getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("day","id","android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        pickerDialog.show();
```

But the problem is, when it reach this line of code

> pickerDialog.getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("day","id","android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);

it will return an error says

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Unfortunately, it works on Android version below 7.0 (Lollipop, marshmallow) , but it doesn't work on Android 7.0 (Nougat).

Anybody could spot the issue? thanks

Comment: The issue would be either there's no such identifier as `["day", "id", "android"]`, or there's no such view in your date picker. Both are easily testable, I think, if you just debug what actually happens.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov , but it works on below version

Comment: Yes, probably because internal implementation has changed in Nougat, which mentioned in couple of places in documentation. Just as I said, it'd be far easier and quicker for you to debug what actually happens rather than waiting for answers here. First check if `getIdentifier` returns zero, then if that's not the case check if picker actually contains that view.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov , okay, i will check for it first, will get back to you for the update. tks

Comment: Rather than trying to hack into somebody else's widgets at runtime, you could implement your own date picker that has your desired functionality. The one that ships with Android is open source, so you could even copy their code and resources to use as a starting point. Or, use a [date picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27), if one of those meets your needs. Having your own code eliminates the sort of problem that you are experiencing here, which you might also be seeing on other devices, where manufacturers or ROM developers have tinkered with `DatePicker`.