# How to show only day and month in date picker dialog in Kotlin(Android)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

I have a datepicker dialog. I only want to show day and month. Year picker dialog must hidden. I already tries other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838437/android-date-selector-with-only-day-and-month) . Nothing works for me. It should also support for Kitkat to Nougat devices. My datepicker code follows.

```
     fun setDatePickerDialog() {
        mDobDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@SignUpActivity, R.style.VDDatePickerDialogTheme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            val newDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
            //dob_textview.setText("($dayOfMonth)  ($monthOfYear)  ($year)")
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(VDAppConstants.DOB_DISPLAY_FORMAT)
            dob_textview?.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate.time))

        }, mNewCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mNewCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mNewCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))

        mNewCalendar.set(1978,
                mNewCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                mNewCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        mDobDialog?.datePicker?.maxDate = mNewCalendar.timeInMillis
    }
```

The following code only works on Kitkat devices but not working on Nougat Devices.

```
 val mDobDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
        // Display Selected date in textbox
        //date.setText("" + dayOfMonth + " " + monthOfYear + ", " + year)
    }, year, month, day)
    mDobDialog.show()


    // Hide Year Selector in Date Picker
    mDobDialog.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("year", "id", "android")).visibility = View.GONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with different code and this code works fine. If you use datepicker theme as Theme_Holo_Dialog then it working fine. Working code as per below.

**Note: It's not working if you set theme Theme_Material_Dialog**

```
package com.wave18.datepickedialogdemo

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Date Picker Dialog
        val dialog = datePickerDialog()

        // Button for Showing Date Picker Dialog
        button_show_date_picker.setOnClickListener {

            // Show Date Picker
            dialog.show()

            // Hide Year Selector
            val year = dialog.findViewById<View>(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("android:id/year", null, null))
            if (year != null) {
                year.visibility = View.GONE
            }


        }


    }

    // Function for Showing Date Picker
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun datePickerDialog(): DatePickerDialog {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Date Picker Dialog
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this@MainActivity, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            // Display Selected date in textbox
            date.text = "$dayOfMonth $monthOfYear, $year"
        }, year, month, day)
        // Show Date Picker

        return datePickerDialog


    }

}
```

[image: Date Picker Dialog without year selector]

Comment: How to get year field from date picker? Could you please add some code

Comment: I am using datepicker dialog

Comment: @VinayakB then do it by second way. Don’t set year

Comment: I don't want to  show year on the dialog. only month and day in the dialog

Comment: @VinayakB I added code end of the answer modify it according to your need and use it with your code it will do it

Comment: This answer works on kitkat devices but not on Api 24 devices. I am getting nullpointer exception on findviewbyid

Comment: I tested with API 26 it working fine given screenshot is from Emulator running on Android 8.0

Comment: I am using real devices. and I am getting this java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference.. Any idea how can I solve this. Because this solution working on other devices below Api 21

Comment: I used below to hide day and month // Hide Day Selector
            val day = dialog.findViewById<View>(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("android:id/day", null, null))
            if (day != null) {
                day.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            // Hide month Selector
            val month = dialog.findViewById<View>(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("android:id/month", null, null))
            if (month != null) {
                month.visibility = View.GONE
            } but calender is displaying at the right side of the dialog